# Can't change the data-directory for MariaDB Centos7.6

Tags: centos7, mariadb, database-administration

I have a fresh install of Centos 7.6 which includes standard partition scheme for Centos 7.6 install. Which includes a "/" directory partition of 50GB.  I would like to move the default nysql (mariadb) data directory so I don't fill up the root partition with a big database.  I want to move the directory to a directory in a user's home directory.  MariaDB will not start after the changes and I don't understand the reason based on the error message.

I have tried following the instructions:

```
# Check the current data-dir
mysql -u root -p
MariaDB [(none)]> select @@datadir;

# Edit the my.cnf file and change:
[mysqld]
datadir=/home/development/mysql
socket=/home/development/mysql/mysql.sock
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
[client]
port=3306
socket=/home/development/mysql/mysql.sock


# Restart MariaDB
systemectl start mariadb
```

## MariaDB fails to start and the following is output.

```
Dec 10 12:19:52 localhost.localdomain mariadb-prepare-db-dir[24554]: Database MariaDB is not initialized, but the directory /home/development/mysql is not empty, so initialization cannot be done.
Dec 10 12:19:52 localhost.localdomain mariadb-prepare-db-dir[24554]: Make sure the /home/development/mysql is empty before running mariadb-prepare-db-dir.
```

The directory in question is in fact empty. The permissions on the folder are mysql:mysql.

Also, I have disabled SELinux entirely with:

```
setenforce 0
```

Here the output of permissions on the home directory:

```
$ ls -haltr /home
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root        root          25 Dec 10 15:41 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 17 root        root         242 Dec 10 15:59 ..
drwx------. 19 development development 4.0K Dec 10 18:00 development

$ ls -haltr /home/development/mysql
total 29M
drwx------.  2 mysql       mysql       4.0K Dec 10 17:56 mysql
drwx------.  2 mysql       mysql       4.0K Dec 10 17:56 performance_schema
-rw-rw----.  1 mysql       mysql         52 Dec 10 17:56 aria_log_control
-rw-rw----.  1 mysql       mysql        16K Dec 10 17:56 aria_log.00000001
-rw-rw----.  1 mysql       mysql       5.0M Dec 10 17:56 ib_logfile1
srwxrwxrwx.  1 mysql       mysql          0 Dec 10 17:56 mysql.sock
-rw-rw----.  1 mysql       mysql        18M Dec 10 17:56 ibdata1
-rw-rw----.  1 mysql       mysql       5.0M Dec 10 17:56 ib_logfile0
drwx------. 19 development development 4.0K Dec 10 18:00 ..
drwxrwxr-x.  4 mysql       mysql        165 Dec 10 18:01
```

and the permissions of the mysql directory itself:

```
ls -haltr /home/development | grep mysql
drwxrwxr-x.  4 mysql       mysql        165 Dec 10 18:01 mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at your systemd mariadb.service script. The default one includes ProtectHome to ensure mysqld cannot access anything under /home/ for security reasons.

Do you have an overwhelmingly good reason to deviate from default paths instead of using a bind-mount? SELinux and other security features are there for very good reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the below actions are performed.

1- **Clean** data directory :

```
rm -rf /home/development/mysql/*
```

2- Give data directory the correct **permissions** :

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /home/development/mysql
```

3- **Copy** the content of the old directory with **preserving** the original permissions :

```
cp -R -p /var/lib/mysql/* /home/development/mysql
```

4- **mysql.sock** path should be the same on **client** & **mysld** section.

5- **Start** mariadb service :

```
systemctl start mariadb
```

EDIT :

I would suggest last thing to create another directory and try within it. If it still not work then go back to /var/lib/mysql backup your database, change /var/lib/mysql name and do a fresh install or initiate mariadb-install-db on the new dir and then restore your database. Also avoid putting a database under home dir, create a dedicated fs because if the user "development" are deleted the database will go with it.

Comment: I followed those instructions, but I still have the error: Dec 10 18:05:26 localhost.localdomain mariadb-prepare-db-dir[3753]: Database MariaDB is not initialized, but the directory /home/development/mysql is not empty, so initialization cannot be done.
Dec 10 18:05:26 localhost.localdomain mariadb-prepare-db-dir[3753]: Make sure the /home/development/mysql is empty before running mariadb-prepare-db-dir.

Comment: MariaDB keep complaining that the directory is not initialized and I have also tried a removable USB drive.

Comment: Could you log the output with `ls -haltr` of the home dir ?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x.  3 root        root          25 Dec 10 15:41 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 17 root        root         242 Dec 10 15:59 ..
drwx------. 19 development development 4.0K Dec 10 18:00 development

Comment: And ls -haltr /home/developement/mysal ?

Comment: I added the output of the permissions of the /home/development/mysql and it's contents to the OP.  It looks to me that MySQL has write permissions on the correct directory.

Comment: I think data directory is corrupted, when you have changed data dir have you stopped mariadb before ? i suggest you to add " innodb_force_recovery=3
innodb_purge_threads=0" and restart in recovery mode then execute "mysqlcheck --all-databases -p" and put the output

Comment: I can change the data directory back to /var/lib/mysql and MariaDB will start fine.

Comment: I would suggest last thing to create another directory and try within it. If it still not work then go back to /var/lib/mysql backup your database, change /var/lib/mysql name and do a fresh install ori initiate mariadb-install-db on the new dir and then restore your database. Also avoid putting a database under home dir, create a dedicate fs because if the user "developement" are deleted the database will go with it.

Comment: YAY!  Thanks! suggestion worked when I created a directory in the home root  -> /home/mysql.   I thought that I had tried that when I tried an external USB hard-drive. I'm not sure why A user directory is not OK, but  If you add that suggestion to your answer I will accept it.

Comment: Good ! Could you make it as resolved :)

Comment: Can you make make that suggestion in your answer -  that a user's home directory is not OK, and I will accept the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102092/discussion-between-jonnyjandles-and-reda-salih).